# Using keytool to change alias password on keystore

Tags: keystore, keytool

My company uses Keystore Explorer for a product we install.  The installation process is ridiculously tedious and I'm trying to automate as much as possible.  The one part I'm stuck on is the certificates.  We give the customer the option of using a *.pfx file from their internal cert authority, or we can generate a self-signed cert and use that.  Either way, we have to edit a keystore file to add in the cert.  If I do the self-signed route with KeyTool, it's working beautifully.  If I use a customer generated *.pfx file, it fails.  After a lot of troubleshooting. This is what I'm doing:

```
$pfxName = pfx File that I'm importing
$pfxPwd = Password for $pfxName
$keystore = Keystore file to which I'm adding the pfx file
$pfxAlias = Alias on $pfxName
$mypwd = Password for $keystore

keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore $pfxName -srcstoretype PKCS12 -srcstorepass $pfxPwd -destkeystore $keystore -srcalias $pfxAlias -destalias $serverFullNameValue -storepass $mypwd
```

If I do this the manual way via KeyStore Explorer, it all works without issue.  After way too much troubleshooting, I discovered, when using KeyStore Explorer, the password for the new alias is the same as the Keystore file.  But if I do it with the script above, the password is the same as the *.pfx file.  I also discovered in the logs that the service that's failing to start cannot read the private key.  So I generated the cert with the above script, then went in and changed the password on the alias created by the *.pfx file to match the keystore file, and suddenly everything worked.

So my question - does anyone know how I can run the import line above to have the new alias use the `$myPwd` value instead of the `$pfxPwd` value?

Answer (score 0):

Probably a more efficient way of doing this, but I added this line immediately after to resolve the issue:

```
keytool -keystore $keystore -keypasswd -new $mypwd -keypass $pfxpwd -alias $pfxAlias -storepass $mypwd
```